# Replacing multiple strings in a character vector withoug using a loop in R

Tags: r

I have script in which I want to replace a set of strings indicated by ##

```
  script <- c("This is #var1# with a mean of #mean1#")
```

My key value list is:

```
  pairs <- list(
             list("#var1#", "Depression"),
             list("#mean1#", "10.1")
           )
```

My loop looks like this and does its job.

```
  for (pair in pairs) {
    script <- gsub(pair[[1]], pair[[2]], script)
  }
```

However, does anybody know a way to solve this **without** using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **stringr**.

As mentioned in `?str_replace`:

> To perform multiple replacements in each element of string, pass a
>   named vector (`c(pattern1 = replacement1)`) to `str_replace_all`.

So in your case:

```
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(script, setNames(sapply(pairs, "[[", 2), sapply(pairs, "[[", 1)))
# [1] "This is Depression with a mean of 10.1"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think with a few changes, you could use the [**`glue`**](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue) package. The changes involve using a `data.frame` to store your key values, and slightly tweaking the formatting of your text.

```
library(glue)

tt <- 'This is {var1} with a mean of {mean1}'

dat <- data.frame(
  'var1' = c('Depression', 'foo'),
  'mean1' = c(10.1, 0),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

glue(tt,
     var1 = dat$var1,
     mean1 = dat$mean1)

This is Depression with a mean of 10.1
This is foo with a mean of 0
```