# Find replace all using dictionary of regex patterns in R (perhaps tidyverse)?

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I would like to replace from a set of patterns to specific string. For example these could be various abbrewiated month names into numeric value of a month.I created a dictionary as follows (Polish months strings 2 numeric value.

```
dictionary<-data.frame(
  from=c("(S|s)tycz(eń|nia)|(S|s)t(y|ycz)",
         "(L|l)ut(y|ego)|(L|l)u(t)",
         "(M|m)ar(ca|zec)|(M|m)ar",
         "(K|k)wie(tnia|cień)|(K|k)wi(|e)",
         "(M|m)aj(a|)", 
         "(C|c)zerw(ca|iec)|(C|c)e(|r|rw)",
         "(L|l)ip(ca|iec)|(L|l)i(|p|c)", 
         "(S|s)ierp(nia|ień)|(S|s)i(|e|er|erp)",
         "(W|w)rze(śnia|sień)|(W|w)rz(|e)",
         "(P|p)aździernik(a|)|(P|p)a(ź|źd|źdź)",
         "(L|l)istopad(a|)|(L|l)is(|t|to|top)",
         "(G|g)rud(nia|zień)|(G|g)ru(|d)" 
  ),
  to=c(" 01 "," 02 "," 03 "," 04 "," 05 "," 06 "," 07 "," 08 "," 09 "," 10 "," 11 "," 12 ")
)
```

I would like to use it on a long column of dirty descriptive strings from which later on I would like to extract dates.

These would be like:

```
Badanie zakończy się 28Wrze2018
```

or

```
Zakończenie badania 28 Września 2018 najpóźniej...
```

And so on for thousands of records

I would like to get

```
Badanie zakończy się 28 09 2018
```

Is there a function or a solution in tidyverse that would do the trick? So far I tried library(DataCombine) but it does not work, does not see my column as text there is probably a bug.

Comment: You can probably use `stringr::str_replace_all`, for instance see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49342467/6656269).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stringr` that would be

```
dictionary <- setNames(
  c(" 01 "," 02 "," 03 "," 04 "," 05 "," 06 "," 07 "," 08 "," 09 "," 10 "," 11 "," 12 "),
  c("(S|s)tycz(eń|nia)|(S|s)t(y|ycz)",
    "(L|l)ut(y|ego)|(L|l)u(t)",
    "(M|m)ar(ca|zec)|(M|m)ar",
    "(K|k)wie(tnia|cień)|(K|k)wi(|e)",
    "(M|m)aj(a|)", 
    "(C|c)zerw(ca|iec)|(C|c)e(|r|rw)",
    "(L|l)ip(ca|iec)|(L|l)i(|p|c)", 
    "(S|s)ierp(nia|ień)|(S|s)i(|e|er|erp)",
    "(W|w)rze(śnia|sień)|(W|w)rz(|e)",
    "(P|p)aździernik(a|)|(P|p)a(ź|źd|źdź)",
    "(L|l)istopad(a|)|(L|l)is(|t|to|top)",
    "(G|g)rud(nia|zień)|(G|g)ru(|d)" 
  )
)
str_replace_all(string, dictionary)
```

However, note that while

```
str_replace_all("Zakończenie badania 28 Września 2018 najpóźniej...", dictionary)
# [1] "Zakończenie badania 28  09  2018 najpóźniej..."
```

works as expected, we get

```
str_replace_all("Badanie zakończy się 28Wrze2018 ", dictionary)
# [1] "Badanie zakończy  08 ę 28 09 e2018 "
```

because `si` is matched for August. Hence, you are going to need to improve the dictionary using your knowledge about the occurrence of those month names.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a situation where you are best served by a `for` loop.

```
convert_date <- function(x){
  dictionary<-data.frame(
    from=c("(S|s)tycz(eń|nia)|(S|s)t(y|ycz)",
           "(L|l)ut(y|ego)|(L|l)u(t)",
           "(M|m)ar(ca|zec)|(M|m)ar",
           "(K|k)wie(tnia|cień)|(K|k)wi(|e)",
           "(M|m)aj(a|)", 
           "(C|c)zerw(ca|iec)|(C|c)e(|r|rw)",
           "(L|l)ip(ca|iec)|(L|l)i(|p|c)", 
           "(S|s)ierp(nia|ień)|(S|s)i(|e|er|erp)",
           "(W|w)rze(śnia|sień)|(W|w)rz(|e)",
           "(P|p)aździernik(a|)|(P|p)a(ź|źd|źdź)",
           "(L|l)istopad(a|)|(L|l)is(|t|to|top)",
           "(G|g)rud(nia|zień)|(G|g)ru(|d)" 
    ),
    to=c(" 01 "," 02 "," 03 "," 04 "," 05 "," 06 "," 07 "," 08 "," 09 "," 10 "," 11 "," 12 "),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

  for (i in seq_len(nrow(dictionary))){
    x <- gsub(dictionary$from[i],
              dictionary$to[i],
              x)
  }

  x
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works too. Thank you for help. But it seems to find only first occurence and then leaves the rest of occurences in the string alone.

Comment: I had miscoded `seq_len(dictionary)`, which should have been `seq_len(nrow(dictionary))`.  Should work as expected now.

Comment: I cannot mark two answers. It should be possible! Thanks a lot!